# Impute Intermediate Missing Values

Tags: r, data.table, zoo

I've the data a group level. The [data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QdTsj_dQalab4XvssdaQqOqeayELibIq) look likes the following.

I actual data is the "Value" & the required data is "Expected_Value".

I tried the following code:

```
setDT(file_to_share)[,Expected_Value := na.locf(na.locf(Value, na.rm=FALSE), fromLast=TRUE),by = c("Group_A",   "Group_B")]
```

But in this code the imputation is done over entire missing value. I want to calculate the missing value if the missing value is in between the values. And missing value will be the replication of the previous available value.

If someone can guide me how to do it then it will be a great help.

**Note** : I tried to calculate using `data.table` and `zoo`. But any other approach will also do.

Comment: Try the complete function in tidyr?

Comment: @reuben: thanks for your comments. No I didn't try tidyr.

Comment: Shouldnt rows `21:23` be also filled?

Comment: @Sotos: No. In Group_2 X Group_1_11 nothing will be filled. That's because there's nothing missing between the 'Value`. I specifically created that example to highlight my issue better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has requested to fill only `NA` values which are between other values within each group. This means to skip any sequence of `NA` values at start or end of each group when applying `zoo::na.locf()`.

With `data.table`, this can be done by identifying the indices of the rows to be skipped and a kind of *anti-join*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)[!DT[, {
  na_grp <- rleid(is.na(Value))
  .I[na_grp %in% c(1L, max(na_grp))]
}, by = .(Group_A, GROUP_B)]$V1, Value := zoo::na.locf(Value)][]
```

> ```
>     Group_A    GROUP_B     Date Value Expected_Value
>  1: GROUP_1  Group_1_1 1/1/2017    NA             NA
>  2: GROUP_1  Group_1_1 1/2/2017    NA             NA
>  3: GROUP_1  Group_1_1 1/3/2017    34             34
>  4: GROUP_1  Group_1_1 1/4/2017    20             20
>  5: GROUP_1  Group_1_1 1/5/2017    20             20
>  6: GROUP_1  Group_1_1 1/6/2017    20             20
>  7: GROUP_1  Group_1_1 1/7/2017    38             38
>  8: GROUP_1  Group_1_2 1/1/2017    35             35
>  9: GROUP_1  Group_1_2 1/2/2017    28             28
> 10: GROUP_1  Group_1_2 1/3/2017    20             28
> 11: GROUP_1  Group_1_2 1/4/2017    32             32
> 12: GROUP_1  Group_1_2 1/5/2017    39             39
> 13: GROUP_1  Group_1_2 1/6/2017    28             28
> 14: GROUP_1  Group_1_2 1/7/2017    NA             NA
> 15: GROUP_2 Group_1_11 1/1/2017    NA             NA
> 16: GROUP_2 Group_1_11 1/2/2017    NA             NA
> 17: GROUP_2 Group_1_11 1/3/2017    40             40
> 18: GROUP_2 Group_1_11 1/4/2017    32             32
> 19: GROUP_2 Group_1_11 1/5/2017    20             20
> 20: GROUP_2 Group_1_11 1/6/2017    NA             NA
> 21: GROUP_2 Group_1_11 1/7/2017    NA             NA
> 22: GROUP_2 Group_1_21 1/1/2017    NA             NA
> 23: GROUP_2 Group_1_21 1/2/2017    32             32
> 24: GROUP_2 Group_1_21 1/3/2017    36             36
> 25: GROUP_2 Group_1_21 1/4/2017    36             36
> 26: GROUP_2 Group_1_21 1/5/2017    28             28
> 27: GROUP_2 Group_1_21 1/6/2017    33             33
> 28: GROUP_2 Group_1_21 1/7/2017    40             40
> 29: GROUP_3 Group_1_13 1/1/2017    NA             NA
> 30: GROUP_3 Group_1_13 1/2/2017    NA             NA
> 31: GROUP_3 Group_1_13 1/3/2017    NA             NA
> 32: GROUP_3 Group_1_13 1/4/2017    29             29
> 33: GROUP_3 Group_1_13 1/5/2017    31             31
> 34: GROUP_3 Group_1_13 1/6/2017    31             31
> 35: GROUP_3 Group_1_13 1/7/2017    34             34
> 36: GROUP_3 Group_1_23 1/1/2017    26             26
> 37: GROUP_3 Group_1_23 1/2/2017    33             33
> 38: GROUP_3 Group_1_23 1/3/2017    27             27
> 39: GROUP_3 Group_1_23 1/4/2017    23             23
> 40: GROUP_3 Group_1_23 1/5/2017    25             25
> 41: GROUP_3 Group_1_23 1/6/2017    41             41
> 42: GROUP_3 Group_1_23 1/7/2017    25             25
>     Group_A    GROUP_B     Date Value Expected_Value
> ```

#### Explanation

- For each group, the streaks of `NA` / non-`NA` values are numbered
- The first and last of these streaks in each group is picked and the indices are retrieved from the special symbol `.I`. (As `Value` will be updated *in place* it doesn't matter whether the first or last streak contains `NA` or not; they will not be updated anyway.)
- The found indices
  `DT[, {na_grp <- rleid(is.na(Value)); .I[na_grp %in% c(1L, max(na_grp))]}, by = .(Group_A, GROUP_B)]$V1`
  are excluded so that `zoo::na.locf(Value)` is only applied to the "inner" streaks of each group.

#### Data

```
DT <- structure(list(Group_A = c("GROUP_1", "GROUP_1", "GROUP_1", "GROUP_1", 
"GROUP_1", "GROUP_1", "GROUP_1", "GROUP_1", "GROUP_1", "GROUP_1", 
"GROUP_1", "GROUP_1", "GROUP_1", "GROUP_1", "GROUP_2", "GROUP_2", 
"GROUP_2", "GROUP_2", "GROUP_2", "GROUP_2", "GROUP_2", "GROUP_2", 
"GROUP_2", "GROUP_2", "GROUP_2", "GROUP_2", "GROUP_2", "GROUP_2", 
"GROUP_3", "GROUP_3", "GROUP_3", "GROUP_3", "GROUP_3", "GROUP_3", 
"GROUP_3", "GROUP_3", "GROUP_3", "GROUP_3", "GROUP_3", "GROUP_3", 
"GROUP_3", "GROUP_3"), GROUP_B = c("Group_1_1", "Group_1_1", 
"Group_1_1", "Group_1_1", "Group_1_1", "Group_1_1", "Group_1_1", 
"Group_1_2", "Group_1_2", "Group_1_2", "Group_1_2", "Group_1_2", 
"Group_1_2", "Group_1_2", "Group_1_11", "Group_1_11", "Group_1_11", 
"Group_1_11", "Group_1_11", "Group_1_11", "Group_1_11", "Group_1_21", 
"Group_1_21", "Group_1_21", "Group_1_21", "Group_1_21", "Group_1_21", 
"Group_1_21", "Group_1_13", "Group_1_13", "Group_1_13", "Group_1_13", 
"Group_1_13", "Group_1_13", "Group_1_13", "Group_1_23", "Group_1_23", 
"Group_1_23", "Group_1_23", "Group_1_23", "Group_1_23", "Group_1_23"
), Date = c("1/1/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/3/2017", "1/4/2017", "1/5/2017", 
"1/6/2017", "1/7/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/3/2017", "1/4/2017", 
"1/5/2017", "1/6/2017", "1/7/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/3/2017", 
"1/4/2017", "1/5/2017", "1/6/2017", "1/7/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/2/2017", 
"1/3/2017", "1/4/2017", "1/5/2017", "1/6/2017", "1/7/2017", "1/1/2017", 
"1/2/2017", "1/3/2017", "1/4/2017", "1/5/2017", "1/6/2017", "1/7/2017", 
"1/1/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/3/2017", "1/4/2017", "1/5/2017", "1/6/2017", 
"1/7/2017"), Value = c(NA, NA, 34L, 20L, NA, NA, 38L, 35L, 28L, 
NA, 32L, 39L, 28L, NA, NA, NA, 40L, 32L, 20L, NA, NA, NA, 32L, 
36L, NA, 28L, 33L, 40L, NA, NA, NA, 29L, 31L, NA, 34L, 26L, 33L, 
27L, 23L, 25L, 41L, 25L), Expected_Value = c(NA, NA, 34L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 38L, 35L, 28L, 28L, 32L, 39L, 28L, NA, NA, NA, 40L, 
32L, 20L, NA, NA, NA, 32L, 36L, 36L, 28L, 33L, 40L, NA, NA, NA, 
29L, 31L, 31L, 34L, 26L, 33L, 27L, 23L, 25L, 41L, 25L)), .Names = c("Group_A", 
"GROUP_B", "Date", "Value", "Expected_Value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-42L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Beautifully written answer. It fulfills all the requirements of mine. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Even though you are after a `data.table` solution, here is one using `tidyverse` methods. (I might try and translate to `data.table` If time permits).

The idea is to create a grouping variable to capture your weeks as well and `fill` Value under grouping GroupA, groupB and week(here called `grp`). We also create a replica of `Value` to `fill` fromlast (`tidyr` terminology is `.direction = 'up'`). We then create another grouping variable with the cumulative sum of `NA` values and replace the values in column `Value` to `NA` under the assumption that the new group size (`Group_A`, `GROUP_B`, `grp` and `grp1`) is 1 and its `value1` is `NA`. That gives the expected result.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(Date, format = '%m/%d/%Y')) %>% 
  mutate(value1 = Value) %>%
  group_by(Group_A, GROUP_B, grp = cumsum(format(Date, '%d')=='01'))%>% 
  fill(Value) %>% 
  fill(value1, .direction = 'up') %>% 
  mutate(grp1 = cumsum(is.na(Value))) %>% 
  group_by(Group_A, GROUP_B, grp, grp1) %>% 
  mutate(new = n(), Value = replace(Value, new == 1 | is.na(value1), NA)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-c(value1, grp, grp1, new))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 42 × 5
>    Group_A   GROUP_B       Date Value Expected_Value
>      <chr>     <chr>     <dttm> <int>          <int>
> 1  GROUP_1 Group_1_1 2017-01-01    NA             NA
> 2  GROUP_1 Group_1_1 2017-01-02    NA             NA
> 3  GROUP_1 Group_1_1 2017-01-03    34             34
> 4  GROUP_1 Group_1_1 2017-01-04    20             20
> 5  GROUP_1 Group_1_1 2017-01-05    20             20
> 6  GROUP_1 Group_1_1 2017-01-06    20             20
> 7  GROUP_1 Group_1_1 2017-01-07    38             38
> 8  GROUP_1 Group_1_2 2017-01-01    35             35
> 9  GROUP_1 Group_1_2 2017-01-02    28             28
> 10 GROUP_1 Group_1_2 2017-01-03    28             28
> # ... with 32 more rows
> ```

```
#Where,

identical(df2$Value, df2$Expected_Value)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I generally don't change my marked answer. But unfortunately Uwe answer is very similar to the way I was approaching. So I had to change my mind. But thanks a lot with your answer. it was equally awesome!!

Comment: I also upvoted some of your answer answers. They are equally very good.

Comment: No problem. Thanks :)